# Openldap, ldap_search_ext_s failover, return IP of correct server

Tags: search, server, ldap, openldap

I have done a ldap init on multiple servers (failover), now using ldap_search_ext_s returns me the users, which were found. So far so good.

The ldap_search_ext_s does the failover automatically, so I cannot tell the users were found at server A or B.

Is there a way to get in the ldap_search_ext_s response the server where the user was found?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, what you're asking is not possible. And it shouldn't matter, the servers should be identical replicas.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yep they should be replicas but it could be that the first serer is down, so I want to list that the users were collected from the second server.

Comment: As I said, it shouldn't matter. And I would not try to expose underlying infrastructure details to clients, for security reasons. But bottom line, there is no option in ldap_search_ext_s to return that data.

Comment: There are some valid use-cases. E.g. a LDAP client wants to check whether it should drop a long-lasting connection dispatched to a remote DC location by the load-balancer to try to reconnect to a nearer replica. Sometimes it's also handy to have that information in the logs to track down issues. So while I'm really eager about LDAP security I allow clients to read the replica's canoncial FQDN. But of course the client has to explicitly query this.